# jQuery pop-up window similar to SoundCloud Stratus

Tags: jquery, popup, soundcloud

I'm embarrassed to be asking this! Working on a music player and need to implement some kind of pop-out-of-window functionality to it so that my visitors can listen while they're navigating all the pages (easier than ajaxing pages in and out).

I've scoured the [Stratus](http://stratus.sc/) source code and have determined that particular behavior is handled through their JS API and it is too complex for me to understand.

So, any recommendations on easiest way to do it in the exact same way? I.E. pretedermined window size, still local to the site, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found the plugin SoundCloud uses:

http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html